# Batch Files Rename Parts of Filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I wand to replace some part of all file names from a folder with something else.

> 123_abc_def.txt, 234_abc1_def1.txt, 333_abc2_edf2.txt 
>   and so on ...
>
> Shoud be:
>   908_abc_def.txt, 
>   908_abc1_def1.txt, 908_abc2_edf2.txt, ...

What I have tried is:

```
echo on
SET data=%~dp0
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=_" %%a in (
'dir /b /a-d "%data%\*_*.txt" '
) Do (

ren "%data%%%a_%%b_%%c" "%data%908_%%b_%%c"
)
```

But I always get a syntax error. What did I do here wrong?

Comment: You cannot rename a file to a directory path, that's why you're getting the syntax error. It should read `ren "%data%%%a_%%b_%%c" "908_%%b_%%c"`, _the destination should be a filename only_.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't see this was wrong with path and file name

Answer (score 0):

Take off the -whatif if it looks good.

```
powershell "dir | ren -newname { $_.name -replace '^...','908' } -whatif"
```

Comment: Can be critical if the filename starts with letters, not digits.

Answer (score 0):

Use this using powershell:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command {Get-ChildItem "FilePath" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "^\d{3}", "908"}
```